# Alamofire with SugarRecord

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I need to know a good example / tutorial that shows how to use these two together. Like an Alamofire request to a direct mapping of its response to an entity managed by SugarRecord.

Comment: Hi Axel, I created an issue on the repository to tackle this. I'll add an example as you mentioned to show you how that can be done. Here's the issue that you can check out:
https://github.com/carambalabs/SugarRecord/issues/281

Comment: thanks, pedro! that would be great!